# Does the saliva of a person just recovered from an infectious disease help to cure another persons having the same disease?

Tags: immunology, antibody, saliva

I have always had this 'weird' thought (But could never quite test it...). Would the saliva of a just recovered person contains antibodies, or other immuno-boosting substances that can help fight off the same pathogen in another person? If yes, is the concentration (dose) of them in saliva enough to have any considerable effect directly (without any further artificial concentration or extraction done)?

Comment: [Cross posting](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/11224/does-the-saliva-of-a-person-just-recovered-from-an-infectious-disease-help-to-cu#11224) on Stack Exchange is [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).  I'm with you that knowledge is our real motivation here, and that sometimes this policy gets in the way... but there are many good reasons for this policy. Are you the same user as a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae? I suggest you close one post and focus on the other.

Comment: It's unfortunate that Health SE is so quiet, I'd love to see it grow and encourage the Biology contributors to interact there as well.  Perhaps in that motivation, and given that your question is probably more on point there, you should close this question and try over there.  Then if your question receives poor response you can request to have it moved/reopened here?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Yep, thats me in Health SE. I have no idea why my name is different on the two sites.. And yes, Health SE is too quiet.